# How can I draw cones are inscribed in and circumscribed about a regular triangular pyramid?

Tags: diagrams, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I want to draw two cones are inscribed in and circumscribed about a regular triangular pyramid. I can not draw with tex. I draw it in GeoSpacW like this
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) using [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en).  Compile with `lualatex`.

If you want "real" 3D you might consider using [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/).  If you want to try TikZ then you should probably also study some of [these examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/).

[image]

You might want change the value of `S` to change the height - if you do that you'll need to adjust `r` so that the red arc meets the diagonals neatly.  Follow the links above for detailed references and other examples.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
        path outer, inner; 
        outer = fullcircle xscaled 144 yscaled 55;
        inner = outer scaled 1/2;

        pair A,B,C,S;

        A = point 14/3 of outer;
        B = point 22/3 of outer;
        C = point  6/3 of outer;

        S = 144 up;
        r = 1/4;

        drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 red);
        draw subpath(+4-r,r) of outer dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
        draw subpath(-4-r,r) of outer -- S -- cycle;
        drawoptions();

        dotlabel.top ("$C$", C) withcolor 1/2 white;

        drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 blue);
        draw inner dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
        draw A--B--C--cycle dashed evenly scaled 1/2;
        draw A--S;
        draw B--S;
        for i=1/4 step 1/4 until 8: 
            draw point i of inner -- S dashed withdots scaled 1/2; 
        endfor

        drawoptions();

        dotlabel.top ("$S$", S);
        dotlabel.llft("$A$", A);
        dotlabel.lrt ("$B$", B);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```